# How can I enable remote debugging for SBT in windows?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, remote-debugging

I would like to accomplish running the equivalent of this

```
sbt -jvm-debug 5005
```

However I don't seem to be able to pass in args in Windows. This is what I am seeing

```
>sbt -jvm-debug 5005
[info] Loading project definition from [myProject]
[info] Set current project to [myProject] (in build file myProject)
[error] Expected letter
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Expected '!'
[error] Expected '+'
[error] Expected '++'
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected key
[error] 5005
[error] ^
[error] Not a valid command: jvm-debug
[error] Not a valid project ID: jvm-debug
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: jvm-debug
[error] jvm-debug
[error]          ^
```

I would like to be able to remote debug this application from Intellij. Any help would be great!

Comment: Where did the sbt shell come from? How did you install it? It appears you're using two different sbt launch scripts. To verify, run `sbt about` with both and paste the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like the Windows version of SBT doesn't define this functionality.

On Linux it is defined in the `$SBT_HOME/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash` as

```
addDebugger () {   
  addJava "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=$1" 
}
```

You can achieve the same result by setting the `SBT_OPTS` environmental variable on Windows.

Run SBT like this, to make the debugger listen on port 5005

```
set SBT_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" && sbt
```

Comment: What does that "&& sbt" at the end of the line mean? doesn't seem like a valid option to me.

Comment: On Linux it executes second command (sbt in this case) if the first command succeeded. Maybe in fact this doesent work on Windows (I dont remember, and I cannot check now). However just skip && and eexecute set and sbt as two separate commands. One after another.

Comment: Does not work (anymore?) on Windows 10 and sbt version 1.3.13.

Answer (score 12):

```
set SBT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
sbt run
```

was the only working solution on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'd downloaded the last updated sbt, exactly sbt 1.3.3 but when I want to enable debug in the project, I had the same problem as you. Investigating, I could see that I haven't this file (sbt-launch-lib.bash) in my own root C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin so when I see in another machine, I could notice that sbt, It was 1.2.8 and yes it had the file that I mentioned before so I uninstalled sbt 1.3.3 and I installed sbt 1.2.8 and put in my project sbt -jvm-debug 9999 and it works.