# SBT, Play Framework 2.6 -jvm -debug on Windows 7

Tags: debugging, playframework, windows-7, jvm, sbt

I'm trying to set up a debug mode in Eclipse for an example project. I'm looking at [this guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/IDE).

When I try to run `-jvm-debug 9999` (I already ran `sbt` command in the project) I have this problem:

[Console example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfv1K.jpg)

**Command:**

`[play-java] $ -jvm-debug 9999 run`

**Result:**

> [warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0

I already put in 4 hours trying to solve this. I have no idea what to do anymore. I've tried with sbt 1.0, now I'm using 0.13.16 (.exe installed).

Answer (score 0):

Found.

[How can I enable remote debugging for SBT in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332378/how-can-i-enable-remote-debugging-for-sbt-in-windows)

"set SBT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
sbt run"

GG