# How to debug a Play java based application in eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, sbt

I know this may be repetitive but couldn't find a proper solution on the internet.I have a Java based play application and I run it using the command 'sbt run'.How do I debug the same application and make it stop at breakpoints??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

And you need to add debug option in your IDE as well, like intellij idea gives you direct button to run your application in debug mode so you dont have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application with the jvm-debug parameter :

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

With Eclipse, after launching the application with the -jvm-debug port, you have to click on "debug configuration..." and then create a new remote java app with host "localhost" and port 9999 (the one you give to the -jvm-debug parameter.
Set some breakpoints and voilà !

Comment: Followed the steps.After creating a new java remote app on the same port and clicking on debug I get the error saying 
[akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode)] Illegal request, responding with stat
us '400 Bad Request': Illegal HTTP message start.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then came across this: [How can I enable remote debugging for SBT in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332378/how-can-i-enable-remote-debugging-for-sbt-in-windows)

What worked for me was entering this command in the console:

```
set SBT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

Now I can run

```
sbt -jvm-debug run
```

without specifying the port number each time and it works fine.